# jquery scroll div right onmouseover

Tags: jquery

i have a right arrow image beside a div,

all i want is for the div to scroll to the right when the mouse is over the right arrow beside it

heres my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".thumbs-right").hover(function() {

        $(this).attr("src","images/arrow-big-right-h.png");
        $('.thumbs').animate({scrollRight: 20 + 'px'}, 600);

    }, function() {

        $(this).attr("src","images/arrow-big-right.png");

    });

});
```

heres the css:

```
.thumbs {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the html:

```
    <div class="thumbs">

        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />
        <img src="images/thumb.png" alt="thumb" />

    </div>

    <img src="images/arrow-big-right.png" alt="right arrow" class="thumbs-right" />
```

it doesnt work at all.

Comment: I can't remember is scrollRight is a valid css, but if it is try putting quotes around it. If that doesn't work try this instead.

$('.thumbs').animate({ left: 20 }, 600);

Comment: I have one thing to say `white-space:nowrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your CSS class...

```
position: relative;
```

Change

```
$('.thumbs').animate({scrollRight: 20 + 'px'}, 600);
```

To

```
$('.thumbs').animate({ left: '20px' }, 600);
```

That gets things moving at least.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g75FS/1/

Answer (score 0):

ok fix your css to this:

```
.thumbs {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbs img {
    position: relative;
}
```

and the js to this:

```
$(".thumbs-right").hover(function() {

    $(this).attr("src","images/arrow-big-right-h.png");
    $('.thumbs img').animate({right:"+=20px"}, 600);
}, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","images/arrow-big-right.png");

});
```

and here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/EfTCz/

Comment: Doesn't this move every item with the thumbs class? I think he meant to actually `scroll` the area inside it

Comment: @Khez, that is true... idk maybe?

Comment: @Khez, i changed my code and the fiddle to move the right things

Comment: @Neal you removed `$(this).stop()` from mouseout, and it's a kinda wonky animation :|

Comment: @Khez, there was never a `.stop()` look that the OP

Comment: not the OP, you. I could've sworn the previous fiddle had a stop() on mouseout.

Comment: @Khez lol no it did not. i just copied and pasted the OP's code and changed it a little

Comment: SO-Ghosts... they're everywhere... they change revision histories... they constantly edit stuff... and... and... and SOpedians don't even know they're there!

Comment: @Khez lol idk, i just looked at the rev history and i still see no `stop()` lol